# $_FILES not showing when submitting the form

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, input, hidden

I'm trying to submit my file input, but when I submit the form and show the output ,the action does not get the $_FILES array.

My file input, I open it by using a jquery click function.(I need it to be hidden because I have another button which I use for the upload)

```
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="filebut">
```

when I select an image, I could get it's filename using javascript, but when I submit the form, and use

```
print_r($_FILES)
```

, it shows an empty array. How could I make the $_FILES array have the data while having the file input hidden?

Comment: Show the rest of your form code. Maybe you forgot the multipart statement.

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie I think you just answered my question, forgot the multipart statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ensure that you include the following:

```
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in your open form tag on your HTML.

e.g.

```
  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        ....
  </form>
```